# Dynamic LINQ date query performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library to generate queries in my project.  I get passed a date string and I want to do the dynamic equivalent of this:

```
db.EntityName
    .Where(x => x.StartDate > DateTime.ParseExact("02/19/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```

I have found that this query below works:

```
db.EntityName
    .Where($"x => x.StartDate.ToFileTime() > { DateTime.ParseExact("02/19/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToFileTime() }")
```

Is this the right approach?  It performs a conversion on `StartDate` so I am not sure if that will cause bad performance.  Is this Ok or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good idea. EF has no idea how to translate `ToFileTime()` to SQL query, so it will just query whole table and perform your `Where` in memory on client. The right way is to use parameters:

```
db.EntityName
    .Where($"x => x.StartDate > @0", DateTime.ParseExact("02/19/2018", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

`@0` represents first parameter in a list, for which we pass parsed `DateTime` object.

If you are not sure if something is bad for perfomance - enable EF logging and see which SQL queries are generated.

Comment: That's much better, thank you very much for the advice.